# How to fix shortcuts in a PyQt5 code?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and python 3.4.3 with PyQt 5.5.1. I've faced with a following problem,when I press Ctrl+Q noting happens.Coud you explain why does it happen and how to solve this problem. My code is below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,  QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 textbox - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 140
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        mainMenu = self.menuBar() 
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Edit')
        viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('View')
        searchMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Search')
        toolsMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Tools')
        helpMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Help')
        exitButton = QAction(QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitButton.setShortcut('CTRL+Q')
        exitButton.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitButton.triggered.connect(self.close)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitButton)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
        QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message - pythonspot.com', "You typed: " + textboxValue, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.textbox.setText("")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not had any problems

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Arch Linux :P, I pressed Ctrl-Q and closed the window.

Comment: Does window close when you click to the menu item? Is the shortcut written in the item near it's text?